# Efficient implementation of a tensor dot product in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have three tensors `x,P,A` of size `(K,N), (K,M), (M,N,N)` respectively. I want to compute a matrix `Y` of size `(K,N)` so that:

[image]

For now I am using the following implementation in tensorflow:

```
PA=tf.einsum('ij,jkl->ikl',P,A)
Y= tf.einsum('ij,ijk->ik', x,PA)
```

I want to know if there are any other effecient procedures to implement this. I tried using inbuilt matrix operations such as `matmul()` and `batch_matmul()` but I am unable to find a solution using them. Any useful suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the notation in the equation. `x` and `A` are rank-2 tensors, but you give each of them only one index. `P` is rank-3, but you give it only two indices.

Comment: No. `A` is a rank-3 tensor and `P` is a rank-2 tensor. I wrote the tensors and their sizes in the same order only.

Comment: My mistake.  The equation might be clearer, though, if you use only "component-style" notation instead of, e.g., giving a rank-3 tensor a single index as a way of expressing a rank-2 one.